# This error occurs, SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal, how should I deal with it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I importa module, such an error occurs. How should I modify it?

```
# sys.path.append('/path/to/your/module')
# from some_module_name import some_function_or_class

# second method
from ..3.1_stack1.Stack import Stack
s1 = Stack()
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd say just change the folder's name

Comment: Also, is Stack.py only in 3.1? Why not copy paste it on the other folders? Assumming this is some kind of homework, if your teacher asks you just for 3.3, will you send them all 3 excercises just so the import works?

Comment: Sorry, these are my own notes while studying the book <Problem Solving With Algorithms And Data Structures Using Python>. 3.1, 3.2 and 3.3 are the three serial numbers of Chapter 3. Thank you very much for your suggestion, I will change the file name.

Answer (score 0):

```
import importlib
import sys

module_directory = "C:/Users/daviid/Documents/test/3.1_excercise/"

sys.path.append(module_directory)

stack = importlib.import_module('Stack')

sys.path.remove(module_directory)

print(stack)
```

You can also import like this, but it's 100 times easier to change the folder's name if you can.

Output:

```
<module 'Stack' from 'C:\\Users/daviid/Documents/test/3.1_excercise\\Stack.py'>
```